# Make a clip as long as a sound using moviepy

Tags: python, moviepy

My clip is 14 minutes long. The sound sometimes can last up to an hour or more. I don't want to make the clip an hour long for example. When I have to make that `clip.set_duration(audio.duration)` it's easy, but how can I make that when the original clip ends, it loops and goes on?

Comment: How can the sound last an hour if the clip is only 14 minutes long?

Comment: @mkrieger1 It's more about the fact that there are two separate audio.mp3 and video.mp4 files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to loop the audio to match the duration of the video clip can use below code

```
from pydub import AudioSegment

audio = AudioSegment.from_file("audio.mp3", format="mp3")

audio_length = len(audio)
desired_length = 14 * 60 * 1000  
num_loops = desired_length // audio_length + 1

looped_audio = audio * num_loops

looped_audio.export("looped_audio.mp3", format="mp3")
```

The same idea can be applied to loop the video so that it lasts as long as the audio

```
from moviepy.video.io.VideoFileClip import VideoFileClip

video = VideoFileClip("video.mp4")

video_duration = video.duration
audio_duration = 61  
num_loops = int(audio_duration / video_duration) + 1

looped_video = video.repeat(num_loops)

looped_video.write_videofile("looped_video.mp4")
```

Comment: Can it be used in reverse? To loop the video so that it lasts as long as the sound?